# How can I compare TimeField model with current time?

Tags: django

I want to compare TimeField with current time and call certain function at that time, how is it possible? or is there any way to do this process?

Comment: Use a schedulign tool like `celery`/`cron`/...

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should at least add some code where your problem is visible to potential helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mktime() function to convert time into seconds passed since epoch in local time. You can then easily compare time.

```
import time
import datetime

given_time_s = int(time.mktime(given_time.timetuple()))

current_time_s = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timetuple()))
```

If you want to call certain function at that, you can use celery to schedule the function with an ETA.

You can find more details about it [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown).